# How can I make this function call every X seconds and change state properly?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to call the function VoltageCheck every X seconds/ or when a button is pressed. When the button is pressed, it works fine, the table is filled as it should, but when the function is called every X seconds, i can see the function called in console, but the table is not filled with the data.

I think it somehow does not setstate properly or idk, i cant figure it out.

The function VoltageCheck works properly, that s why i did not put it here.

```
class MyAppState extends ChangeNotifier {
//Here are defined the functions and variables used including "listaContoateTensiuni"
}
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  var appState = MyAppState();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 5), (Timer t) async {
      appState.listaContoareTensiuni.clear();
      var data = await VoltageCheck(169);
      setState(() {
        appState.listaContoareTensiuni = data;
      });
    });
  }

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var appState = context.watch<MyAppState>();

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(59, 255, 252, .8),
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Home'),
      ),
      body: Center(
       child: Column(
        children:  [
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                appState.listaContoareTensiuni.clear();
                var data = await VoltageCheck(169);
                appState.listaContoareTensiuni = data;
                setState(() {});
              },
              child: Text("Refresh Tensiuni",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Color.fromRGBO(5, 5, 5, .8),
                      fontSize: 15,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
            ),
          DataTable(
                horizontalMargin: 0,
                dataRowColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith(
                    appState._getDataRowColor),
                dataRowHeight: 30,
                headingRowHeight: 50,
                border: TableBorder.all(
                    color: Color.fromARGB(255, 4, 34, 32),
                    style: BorderStyle.solid,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    width: 2),
                columnSpacing: 0,
                columns:
                    appState.getColumns_tensiuni(appState.columns_tensiuni),
                rows:
                    appState.getRows_tensinui(appState.listaContoareTensiuni)),
])
)
```

I have tried puting the setState() here, creating a function with notifyListeners() in MyAppState, combinations of these 2 but none of them works.

Comment: What's appState look like?  Are you copying the data?  Maybe you're updating something that has already been copied and is no longer being viewed.  Or did you forget to use notifyListeners() in the ChangeNotifier.  Or subscribe to the changes?

Comment: The app state looks something like this:
`
  class MyAppState extends ChangeNotifier {
     void Verificare_Tensiuni(int address) async {
        listaContoareTensiuni.clear();
        var data = await VoltageCheck(169);
        listaContoareTensiuni = data;

        last_check = DateTime.now();
        last_check_string = DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm').format(last_check);

        notifyListeners();
  }
}`

I think subscribing to the changes it not a problem, because when I call this function when tapping a button, it works fine.
The problem comes when it calls from initstate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `setState` is not a public method, only `this` can call it for it's own state (as in `this.setState`). Flutter has a widget just for that problem, `StreamBuilder` will rebuild on every new event on the sink.

In this example i opted for the `.broadcast` just split the periodic logic form the widget builder.

```
class App extends StatefulWidget {
  App({super.key});

  @override
  State<App> createState() => _App();
}

class _App extends State<App> {
  late final Timer _timer;
  final _nums = StreamController<int>.broadcast();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _nums.stream.listen(
      (i) => counter += i,
    );
    _timer = Timer.periodic(
      Duration(seconds: 1),
      (tick) => _nums.add(1),
    );
  }

  int counter = 0;

  Widget streamed_widget(BuildContext ctx, AsyncSnapshot<int> snap) {
    return Text("$counter += ${snap.data!}");
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              StreamBuilder(
                initialData: 0,
                stream: _nums.stream,
                builder: streamed_widget,
              ),
              InkWell(
                child: Text('Add 100'),
                onTap: () => _nums.add(100),
              ),
              InkWell(
                child: Text('Sub 100'),
                onTap: () => _nums.add(-100),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried this method and it works... somehow
It updates the data as it should, but it is being called continuously, it does not respect the interval of seconds given.
Also do you know any method to not return a widget? Because I dont rly need to return anything, just to update some data in the background.

Comment: This is how i tried to implement it

`StreamBuilder<int>(
              stream: Stream.periodic(Duration(seconds: 10), (i) => i),
              builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<int> snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  appState.Verificare_Tensiuni(169);
                }
                return Text(""); 
              },`

Comment: But what is the issue that you are having now? ; there is no way to update a widget without rebuilding it in some way (that menas that *new value == new state or widget*)